# Georeferencer PDF Image missing data

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, pdf

I am very new to QGIS and have been using it to create some Georeferenced overlays of aerial photographs and title plans.
I have sucessfully completed it several times but have come up against a problem that is really making me scratch my head.
Using the same PDF Title Plan that has previously worked, if I go to Georeferencer, open new raster and drop in the PDF I get half a document. No map, but only the red text below it. Nothing else at all. If I use a similar title plan, it works perfectly.
I assumed perhaps a failed PDF but I sent it to my friend who has added it first time - no problems.
Fresh install of 3.22 and the same results.
This is what he gets ...
[image]

and this is what I get
[image]

But if I use a different Title Plan - it works perfectly.
The PDF opens absolutely fine on any other software.
I even opened the PDF externally and "printed" it to a new PDF - same results.

Im baffled and also very new - so go easy!
Any idea where I might look to fix this?

Comment: Why are you referencing the PDF again, when you already referenced it? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: again - in that I am repeating the project at a later time. 
the last time i did it, it worked - but when i tried to do it months later on a new project it no longer works. 
Im not repeating it within the same project.

Comment: I have Erik's question as well.  You might consider converting the "problem" pdf to a jpg or tif raster and georeferncing that, and with future pdfs exporting them to raster after georeferencing them.

Comment: as above really. Im just baffled as to why this one just doesnt show any black mapping, but shows the red text. I did convert to jpg and it is a workaround - but the root of the issue still evades me.

Comment: But why are you georeferencing the same image a second time?

Comment: Im not. This is a new project - same PDF. 
I have completed this process before - using the same files - but didnt save it or deleted it. I carrying out the same steps as I did before - but on a new project,

Comment: When you say it used to work for you and it used to work for your friend, what version of QGIS were you using? Is this just a QGIS 3.22.0 problem because .0 releases do tend to have more bugs. Also there are new settings around raster display in 3.22 that may conflict with stored raster settings for this particular pdf (maybe in the associated .xml file from your last attempt at georeferencing?) If you delete the .xml file I wonder if it works properly again. Since you mentioned you had no problem with other pdfs that presumably you did not georeference before.

Comment: Worked fine on the version I had before and then didn't. Possibly 3.18. After I updated it still didn't work. Issue didn't replicate on my friends system at all across the same two versions he has. So it's isolated to my machine. I will look out that XML file and see if I can find it and delete it. Although I did totally remove Q-GiS during the upgrade that XML might still be lurking somewhere.

Comment: I even just tried dragging that PDF in as a layer - without using the GeoReferencer - and it again only shows the text at the bottom of the document - not any of the map.

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply - somehow the comment replies didn't show up in my inbox.) The .xml file I'm talking about has the same name as your PDF file and is usually in the same location as the PDF file. QGIS presumably reads this xml file along with your PDF to interpret how to display it in either georeferencer or the canvas. Deleting QGIS does not delete this file. Are you able to find this file?

Comment: I looked for it and deleted it. It still didn't work though. I ended up opening the pdf in GIMP and then saving it as a new PDF. It worked first time after this.